# Knex Js SQLITE3 Sum returning promise instead of sum value

Tags: sqlite, promise, knex.js

I am working on knexjs and sqlite 3 
in that

```
function cred1() {
  return knex("main").sum("cr as cr")
    .where('supplier',data.supplier)
    .then(function(res){
      return res
    });
}
```

This is returning

```
Promise {
_bitField: 0,
_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
_rejectionHandler0: undefined,
_promise0: undefined,
_receiver0: undefined }
```

But I need the value of sum

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not properly making call to this function- Should do something like this-

```
cred1()
.then((result) =>{
   console.log(result);
});
```

If this not work, share how you are calling this promise function.